# Make text follow a vertical instead of a horizontal route in an input form

Tags: html, css

I am creating a chatbox where a user needs to write his text in an input box but the text instead of continuing vertically, it continues horizontally without changing line. Any one could help?

```css
#usr_inp {
  overflow: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #B3B0AE;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="user_input" id="usr_inp" placeholder="Enter Text Here" value="">
  <btn class='submit-btn' type="submit">Submit</btn>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `textarea` to get it to display on many lines:

```
<textarea name="my_input" id="myId" cols="4" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: Great, that seems to work. Any way to take out the decoration it has on the right and bottom side?

Comment: @Kostis you can add any additional styling by applying a `class` or `id`. Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/o44s8nLj/

Comment: textarea {
    resize: none;
}